# When you are enjoying a good nutrition

Tags: sentence-choice, sentence-usage

I am an athlete and I have very good eating habits. Let's suppose I have changed my coach already and the new one tends to find out wheather I eat high-quality meals or not and in total he is going to discover about my "nutrition". How shall I inform him in a natural and idiomatic way:

- I have a good nutrition.
- I nutrish well.

I am looking for a way in which I can use the word "nutrition".

Comment: Or   *"I am well nourished"*

Answer (score 4):

Side note: I think you should have a longer discussion with your coach. Even if he will disagree with you. Even if you will ignore his advice. He may still have some good insights. "Fooling" him with buzzwords may not be in your advantage.

If I were in a similar situation, I would build a sentence like:

> I am careful to follow a (very) **nutritious** diet.

I am not sure "nutrition" in itself would sound very good in this context.

But this kind of answer is the best candidate to attract questions from the coach, asking for clarifications / details.

---

Note: I use "diet" with the dictionary meaning (sum of food eaten) and not the Cosmopolitan meaning (method of weight loss).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, neither of your sentences use the word "nutrition" correctly. Further to that, "nutrition", although a widely-used and understood word, tends to be used in scientific, or medical context. As such, it is rarely used in the kinds of context in which you are trying to use it.

If you must use the word "nutrition" or a form of it, here are some examples:

- I eat nutritious food.
- I follow a nutritious diet.
- I eat food with a high nutrition value.

You will notice that in all these examples, "nutritious" is a property of the *food* you eat and not something that describes yourself. You would rarely hear "*I am well nourished*" from a native English speaker as it sounds very formal and not at all like everyday speech.

A more natural, everyday way to express that you have a good diet would be, perhaps:

- I prefer *healthy* eating
- I eat *well* (although this can mean different things to different people)
- I follow a *healthy diet*

Comment: So what would be the most natural way in everyday speech to convey the same message then?